# Spring boot (with Scala) unable to instantiate DataSource [No supported DataSource type found]

Tags: scala, spring-boot, jdbc

When I run my stand-alone web application, spring is failing to instantiate the datasource bean. Please note that I don't want to use JPA or hibernate in this project. At this point I have no idea why. My best guess is a dependency or a syntax issue but I have not been able to find a resolution to my problem.

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'gameoo' defined in class path resource [com/hf/database/Datasource.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [javax.sql.DataSource]: Factory method 'get' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: No supported DataSource type found
```

If anyone has some insight or can help me resolve this issue that'd be great.

Below is my "spring.properties" file

```
# Datasource properties
spring.datasource.driver-class-name = com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
spring.datasource.url = jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/gameoo?autoReconnect=true&useSSL=true
spring.datasource.username = user
spring.datasource.password = pass
spring.datasource.initialSize = 1
spring.datasource.maxActive = 5

# HikariCP settings (spring.datasource.hikari.*)
spring.datasource.hikari.connection-timeout = 60000 #60 sec
spring.datasource.hikari.maximum-pool-size = 5      # max 5
```

The datasource class that is causing issues:

```
import javax.sql.DataSource
import org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationProperties
import org.springframework.boot.jdbc.DataSourceBuilder
import org.springframework.context.annotation.{Bean, Configuration, Primary, PropertySource}

@Configuration
@PropertySource(Array("classpath:spring.properties"))
class Datasource {
    @Primary
    @Bean(name = Array("gameoo"))
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "spring.datasource")
    def get: DataSource = {
        DataSourceBuilder.create().build()
    }
}
```

My main application class is as follows

```
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan


@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan(Array[String]("com.hf"))
class AppRunner


object HexFrontier
{
    def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
        System.setProperty("spring.config.name", "spring")
        SpringApplication.run(classOf[AppRunner])
    }
}
```

Lastly below is my gradle dependency file

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'scala'
}

group 'com.hf'
version '1.0'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

sourceCompatibility = 1.8

sourceSets {
        main.java.srcDirs = ['src/main/hf']
        test.java.srcDirs = ['src/test/hf']
        main.resources.srcDirs = ['src/main/resources']
}

configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy.cacheChangingModulesFor 1, 'minutes'
}

compileJava {
    options.compilerArgs += ["-proc:none"]
}

dependencies {
    // Scala
    compile('org.scala-lang:scala-library:2.12.8')

    // Spring
    compile group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot', version: '2.1.2.RELEASE'
    compile group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-autoconfigure', version: '2.1.2.RELEASE'
    compile group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-web', version: '2.1.2.RELEASE'
    compile group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-actuator', version: '2.1.2.RELEASE'
    compile group: 'org.springframework', name: 'spring-core', version: '5.1.5.RELEASE'
    compile group: 'org.springframework', name: 'spring-beans', version: '5.1.5.RELEASE'
    compile group: 'org.springframework', name: 'spring-context', version: '5.1.5.RELEASE'
    compile group: 'org.springframework', name: 'spring-web', version: '5.1.5.RELEASE'
    compile group: 'org.springframework', name: 'spring-webmvc', version: '5.1.5.RELEASE'
    compile group: 'org.springframework', name: 'spring-aop', version: '5.1.5.RELEASE'
    compile group: 'org.springframework', name: 'spring-jdbc', version: '5.1.5.RELEASE'
//    compile group: 'org.springframework.data', name: 'spring-data-commons', version: '2.1.4.RELEASE'

    // servlets
    compile group: 'javax.servlet', name: 'javax.servlet-api', version: '4.0.1'
    compile group: 'javax.persistence', name: 'javax.persistence-api', version: '2.2'
    compile group: 'javax.transaction', name: 'jta', version: '1.1'
    compile group: 'javax.xml.bind', name: 'jaxb-api', version: '2.1'
    compile group: 'javax.validation', name: 'validation-api', version: '1.0.0.GA'
    compile group: 'javax.servlet.jsp', name: 'javax.servlet.jsp-api', version: '2.3.3'
    compile group: 'javax.annotation', name: 'javax.annotation-api', version: '1.3.2'

    // mysql jdbc
    compile group: 'mysql', name: 'mysql-connector-java', version: '8.0.15'

    // Logging
    compile group: 'org.apache.logging.log4j', name: 'log4j-core', version: '2.11.0'
    compile group: 'org.apache.logging.log4j', name: 'log4j-api', version: '2.11.0'

    // JSON / Yaml / Config support
    compile group: 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core', name: 'jackson-core', version: '2.9.8'
    compile group: 'com.fasterxml.jackson.module', name: 'jackson-module-scala_2.12', version: '2.9.8'
    compile group: 'com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat', name: 'jackson-dataformat-yaml', version: '2.9.8'
    compile group: 'com.typesafe', name: 'config', version: '1.3.3'

    // Testing
    testCompile group: 'org.hamcrest', name: 'hamcrest-all', version: '1.3'
    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.12'
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Failed to instantiate [javax.sql.DataSource]: Factory method 'get'
>   threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException:
>   No supported DataSource type found

If you do not set the DataSource class name by calling `type()` before `build()` , `DataSourceBuilder` will scan the classpath to find the following DataSource classes in order . If none are found , this error will happen.

1. `com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource` (HikariCP)
2. `org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSource`  (Tomcat DB Connection Pool)
3. `org.apache.commons.dbcp2.BasicDataSource` (Commons DBCP2)

So you have to include `HikariCP` in `build.gradle` . Or simply use `spring-boot-starter-jdbc` which will automatically get a  `HikariCP` and `spring-jdbc` and  define a `DataSource` bean for you .

So I suggest to revise `build.gradle` as follow:

```
compile group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-jdbc', version: '2.1.2.RELEASE'

//No need as spring-boot-starter-jdbc automatically get this
//compile group: 'org.springframework', name: 'spring-jdbc', version: '5.1.5.RELEASE'
```

Comment: That was exacly my issue thank you so much for that explanation \o/.